# excel handling in SOAP UI

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

I am new to groovy and I wrote this code to fetch data from excel through groovy in SOAP UI.
The below code has the error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [0, 0] Possible solutions: getCell(java.lang.String), getCell(int, int), getPLS(), getClass(), getName(), getRows() error at line: 30

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*

def value1
def value2
def value3


//pull value from test suite properties
def RowSelector = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("RowSelector")

//Read Excel
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\JAVA\\myWorkspace\\SOAPUIExcelProject\\SOAPTestData.xls"))

//creating a copy to save results in
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\JAVA\\myWorkspace\\SOAPUIExcelProject\\Output.xls"), wb)

File datasheet = new File("C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\ext\\dataSheets\\ResultTemp.xls")

if (datasheet.exists()) {
   log.info("Exist")
}
else {
   log.info("Blank")
}

// loading Values from Excel (A1) to TestSuite properties

value1 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(0, RowSelector).getContents() //cell A1
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "TestSuitevalue1", value1 )
log.info("Value1 Is: " + value1)

// loading Values from Excel (B1) to TestSuite properties

Value2 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(1, RowSelector).getContents() //Cell B1
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "TestSuitevalue2", value2 )
log.info("Value2 Is: " + value2)



// loading Values from Excel (C1) to TestSuite properties

Value3 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(2, RowSelector).getContents() //Cell C1
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "TestSuitevalue3", value3 )
log.info("Value3 Is: " + value3)
wb.close()
```

Comment: From the error, it shows that RowSelector is coming as String. RowSelector has to be Integer according to the API. (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html). Try casting RowSelector to Integer.

Comment: Please can you just comment on how to do casting in groovy.

Comment: testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("RowSelector")?.toInteger() should work.